# Cut&paste losing main?

Tags: java

**Background:**

I am trying to learn java and wanted to try out printing hello world as my first program, and asked my friend to send one to me. He said I was lazy and didn't want to do the work, but he did send me one program, reluctantly.

This is the code he sent.

```
public class af {
    public static void mаin(String [] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

**What I tried:**
I cut&pasted it into gvim, but I get the following error when I try to run it (it compiles fine).

**Error:** Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main

> **But, when I actually do the work of typing it out (as he wanted me to),
>   it works!**

**The question:**

How does this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I attempted to paste this into my IDE, and it pointed out to me that

> Some characters cannot be mapped using "Cp1252" character encoding.

It highlighted the character that could not be mapped, and it highlighted the "a" in `public static void m`**`a`**`in`

After changing the `а` to a normal `a`, the code worked fine.

The `a` must be some sort of different character that looks like an `a`. Try typing in the `a` again and trying again.